# Take and a array of names and values and create a dropdown that can set the values based on the objects attribute values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to figure how to set a select dropdown to the correct value of an object when returning back to a form. Here is what I have so far.

In my model I have an array that holds the name and value for a color select dropdown.

```
ROW_COLORS = [["Green", "greenTableRow"], ["Red", "redTableRow"], ["Orange", "orangeTableRow"], ["Yellow", "yellowTableRow"]]
```

I then set the `ROW_COLORS` to a variable `@row_colors` in the controller.

I am looping through an array of rule objects in my view...

```
<% rule_formats.each do |rule| %>
```

And every existing `rule` has an attribute called `color_class`.

Then in my form, I am trying to create a dropdown list with the color names (ex. `green`) from the array with the value of each color (`greenTableRow`) being the `color_class`.

```
<%= f.select("column_color", options_from_collection_for_select(@row_options, rule.color_class),  {include_blank: "-- Select Color --", class: 'span7'}) %>
```

This however errors out with a `wrong number of arguments (2 for 3..4)`.

I know that if `@row_options` was an object I could then do something like `options_from_collection_for_select(@row_options, :color_class, :name, rule.color_class)` But since `@row_options` is just an array.. I'm not sure if I'm even using the correct helper_method.

I cannot find how to set the color select to the correct value using `rule.color_class` when the user returns to a previously submitted form.

Answer (score 1):

try using [`options_for_select`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select) instead of `options_from_collection_for_select`.

`options_from_collection_for_select` expects you to pass it ruby objects, whereas `options_for_select` expects an array of douples, which appears to be what you have

Comment: Awesome! That was it!... Such an easy fix.